# I cannot activate or deactivate plugins in wp-admin area or using wp-cli

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

I have a problem on a client's live WordPress site where I am unable to activate or deactivate plugins. I am an administrator and used to be able to do this. I can add new plugins but not activate.

I'd be grateful for any insight into what I can try next.

I am using v5.2.4 of WordPress with v7.3 of PHP and MariaDB.

In wp-admin when I try to activate a plugin, I see a Successfully Activated message but nothing has actually happened. I see the same behaviour in wp-cli. See pasted code below.

I've seen posts where others had the same problem.

One suggested answer is to delete all plugins from the file system. I am reluctant to do this as it is a live client site, but I have deactivated mainwp-child as it does not affect visitors to the site.

The other suggested answer is that maybe the options table in the database has become corrupted. I was able to update the active_plugins record in the database to deactivate a plugin, so I don't think it is this.

```
linuxuser@aws-server:~/files$ wp plugin list
+-------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------+------------+
| name                          | status   | update                         | version    |
+-------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------+------------+
| all-in-one-wp-security-and-fi | inactive | none                           | 4.4.2      |
| rewall_old_                   |          |                                |            |
| classic-editor                | active   | none                           | 1.5        |
| contact-form-7                | active   | none                           | 5.1.5      |
| youtube-embed-plus            | active   | none                           | 13.1.2.1   |
| google-analytics-for-wordpres | active   | none                           | 7.10.0     |
| s                             |          |                                |            |
| limit-login-attempts-reloaded | inactive | none                           | 2.9.0      |
| rankya-localbusiness-markup-s | active   | none                           | 1.1        |
| chema                         |          |                                |            |
| mainwp-child                  | active   | none                           | 4.0.4      |
| spinupwp                      | active   | none                           | 1.1.2      |
| stream                        | inactive | none                           | 3.4.2      |
| updraftplus                   | active   | version higher than expected   | 2.16.20.24 |
| vc_clipboard                  | active   | none                           | 3.25       |
| js_composer                   | active   | none                           | 6.0.5      |
| goodbye-captcha               | active   | none                           | 3.1.34     |
| wp-bruiser-contactform7       | active   | none                           | 3.1.34     |
| wp-mail-smtp                  | active   | none                           | 1.7.1      |
| wordpress-seo                 | active   | none                           | 12.5       |
| spinupwp-debug-log-path       | must-use | none                           | 1.0        |
| object-cache.php              | dropin   | none                           |            |
+-------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------+------------+
```

I managed to deactivate `all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall` by renaming it and updating the options table in the database. I want to activate limit-login-attempts-reloaded

```
linuxuser@aws-server:~/files$ wp plugin activate limit-login-attempts-reloaded
Plugin 'limit-login-attempts-reloaded' activated.
Success: Activated 1 of 1 plugins.
```

But it didn't:

```
+-------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------+------------+
| name                          | status   | update                         | version    |
+-------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------+------------+
| all-in-one-wp-security-and-fi | inactive | none                           | 4.4.2      |
| rewall_old_                   |          |                                |            |
| classic-editor                | active   | none                           | 1.5        |
| contact-form-7                | active   | none                           | 5.1.5      |
| youtube-embed-plus            | active   | none                           | 13.1.2.1   |
| google-analytics-for-wordpres | active   | none                           | 7.10.0     |
| s                             |          |                                |            |
| limit-login-attempts-reloaded | inactive | none                           | 2.9.0      |
| rankya-localbusiness-markup-s | active   | none                           | 1.1        |
| chema                         |          |                                |            |
| mainwp-child                  | active   | none                           | 4.0.4      |
| spinupwp                      | active   | none                           | 1.1.2      |
| stream                        | inactive | none                           | 3.4.2      |
| updraftplus                   | active   | version higher than expected   | 2.16.20.24 |
| vc_clipboard                  | active   | none                           | 3.25       |
| js_composer                   | active   | none                           | 6.0.5      |
| goodbye-captcha               | active   | none                           | 3.1.34     |
| wp-bruiser-contactform7       | active   | none                           | 3.1.34     |
| wp-mail-smtp                  | active   | none                           | 1.7.1      |
| wordpress-seo                 | active   | none                           | 12.5       |
| spinupwp-debug-log-path       | must-use | none                           | 1.0        |
| object-cache.php              | dropin   | none                           |            |
+-------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------+------------+
```

This is the update statement I ran and committed in the database:

```
update options 
set option_value = 'a:15:{i:0;s:33:"classic-editor/classic-editor.ph
p";i:1;s:36:"contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php";i:2;s:35:"goodbye-ca
ptcha/goodbye-captcha.php";i:3;s:50:"google-analytics-for-wordpress/goo
gleanalytics.php";i:4;s:27:"js_composer/js_composer.php";i:5;s:29:"main
wp-child/mainwp-child.php";i:6;s:73:"rankya-localbusiness-markup-schema
/rankya-localbusiness-markup-schema.php";i:7;s:21:"spinupwp/spinupwp.ph
p";i:8;s:17:"stream/stream.php";i:9;s:27:"updraftplus/updraftplus.php"
;i:10;s:29:"vc_clipboard/vc_clipboard.php";i:11;s:24:"wordpress-seo/wp-
seo.php";i:12;s:51:"wp-bruiser-contactform7/wp-bruiser-contactform7.php
";i:13;s:29:"wp-mail-smtp/wp_mail_smtp.php";i:14;s:30:"youtube-embed-pl
us/youtube.php";}'
where option_name = 'active_plugins';
```

The plugin is still displayed in the output from wp-cli though:

```
array (
  0 => 'goodbye-captcha/goodbye-captcha.php',
  1 => 'all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/wp-security.php',
  2 => 'classic-editor/classic-editor.php',
  3 => 'contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php',
  4 => 'google-analytics-for-wordpress/googleanalytics.php',
  5 => 'js_composer/js_composer.php',
  6 => 'mainwp-child/mainwp-child.php',
  7 => 'rankya-localbusiness-markup-schema/rankya-localbusiness-markup-schema.php',
  8 => 'spinupwp/spinupwp.php',
  9 => 'updraftplus/updraftplus.php',
  10 => 'vc_clipboard/vc_clipboard.php',
  11 => 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php',
  12 => 'wp-bruiser-contactform7/wp-bruiser-contactform7.php',
  13 => 'wp-mail-smtp/wp_mail_smtp.php',
  14 => 'youtube-embed-plus/youtube.php',
)
```

It is not in the database active_plugins (select statement run after mainwp_child deactivated):

```
MariaDB [dbname]> select option_value
    -> from pfx_options
    -> where option_name = 'active_plugins';
| option_value              
| a:13:{i:0;s:35:"goodbye-captcha/goodbye-captcha.php";i:2;s:33:"classic-editor/classic-ed
itor.php";i:3;s:36:"contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php";i:4;s:50:"google-analytics-for-w
ordpress/googleanalytics.php";i:5;s:27:"js_composer/js_composer.php";i:7;s:73:"rankya-loca
lbusiness-markup-schema/rankya-localbusiness-markup-schema.php";i:8;s:21:"spinupwp/spinupw
p.php";i:9;s:27:"updraftplus/updraftplus.php";i:10;s:29:"vc_clipboard/vc_clipboard.php";i:
11;s:24:"wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php";i:12;s:51:"wp-bruiser-contactform7/wp-bruiser-contactfo
rm7.php";i:13;s:29:"wp-mail-smtp/wp_mail_smtp.php";i:14;s:30:"youtube-embed-plus/youtube.p
hp";} |
```

If you've made it this far, thank you. If you've any ideas I'd really be glad to try them.

Kind regards,

Anita

Comment: Looks like a caching issue. You can try to delete all kind of caches. And/or setting `WP_CACHE` in `wp-config.php` file to `false` and then `true` again

Comment: Thank you. 
I turned off the page cache (which was excluding `/wp-admin`) and purged all caches. Same problem. I defined `WP_CACHE` as false in the `wp-config.php` file, and purged the object cache. Plugin activated properly. 
I recently migrated site from another server and was using Breeze as a caching solution. On the new server there is an external page cache solution, so Breeze is unnecessary. If I hadn't cleared the cache from Breeze before I uninstalled it, could that have caused this problem?
How do I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: Just to add to this. the `WP_CACHE` constant is still false. I am having to clear the object cache before I activate or deactivate any plugin. Strange but an easier workaround than playing with the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned at the comment section of question, it looks like a cache issue.

In this very example it was probably related to `object-cache.php` and/or as you evaluated the Breeze. I cannot say something specific without reproducing the problem.

However, *IMHO*, **while playing in production, if you change something in code and can't see the assumed output, it is most probably cached** or you changed the wrong file or your code has not been deployed.

Bets are always on cache. Good luck next time.